# Android BluetoothDevice createBond permissions error

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have a project with both

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

In it I make a call to scan for BT devices using (simplified):

```
final BluetoothLeScanner scanner = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        .getBluetoothLeScanner()
ArrayList<ScanFilter> scanFilters = ArrayList<>();
scanFilters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder()
        .setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(MY_SERVICE_UUID))
        .build());
ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .build();
ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {}
    @Override
    void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        result.getDevice().createBond();
        scanner.stopScan(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {}
};
scanner.startScan(scanFilters, scanSettings, scanCallback);
```

The gist is that I scan for a device with my service, and for now just bond to the first one I see. All my characteristics and descriptors are using read/write_encrypted permissions (I don't know if that matters). What I end up seeing is the pairing screens on both devices but later when I use the `connectGatt` method I fail with the following error:

```
E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_cache_load: can't open GATT cache file /data/misc/bluetooth/gatt_cache_76fe0b7bf8dd for reading, error: No such file or directory
E/bt_att: gatt_disc_cmpl_cback() - Unable to register for service changed indication
```

If, on the other hand, I open the BT settings and bond the devices from there, everything works great! `connectGatt` works and I can read/write data as I please.

What am I doing wrong with `createBond()`?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue right now.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: It appears we did, though still flushing out the final details. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that calling `BluetoothDevice.createBond()` uses `BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_AUTO` to create the bond. This doesn't work across all Android platforms and is brittle. Instead, making the call with the specific transport used to scan for the device did the trick.

```
device.createBond(BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
```

Comment: Have you tried to retry the `createBond()` method several times to see if it goes through instead?  You might've gotten a **137** error that can be circumvented like that.